# Reduced relative clauses referring to a whole sentence

Tags: grammaticality, participles, reduced-relative-clauses

> 1a- The station chief was fired, ***meaning*** there is an open position.
>
> 2a- We argued over something meaningless, ***making*** me feel bad.
>
> 3a- Dr. Gregory House is often brooding, ill-humored, and pessimistic,
> ***leading*** to interpersonal discord.

Are these sentences above grammatically correct and can I rewrite them as follows?

> 1b- The station chief was fired, ***which means*** there is an open
> position.
>
> 2b- We argued over something meaningless, ***which made*** me feel bad.
>
> 3b- Dr. Gregory House is often brooding, ill-humored, and pessimistic,
> ***which leads*** to interpersonal discord.

Comment: Yes, you can. Note, though, that your first three examples are not 'reduced' relative clauses (there's no such thing), but gerund-participial clauses (functioning as adjuncts with a resultative interpretation).

Comment: @BillJ: I notice you often say some particular syntactic category doesn't exist, or isn't called whatever the OP *thought* it was. I don't normally take much notice, because I'm not that big on terminology in the first place, but I can't help noticing that Wikipedia has [what looks like a clear-cut definition:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause) *a relative clause that is not marked by an explicit relative pronoun or complementizer such as **who, which** or **that**.* Is there a single online resource listing the syntactic categories that *you* accept as valid & meaningful?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is this sentence b also acceptable? a: " The detectives give off a passive and obvious vibe that lets her know that exatcly what they think, which is that she is guilty" b: " The detectives give off a passive and obvious vibe that lets her know that exatcly what they think, being that she is guilty. "

Comment: Your phrasing in (a) is valid, but (b) is at least "non-idiomatic" (probably "syntactically invalid" in some way, but I wouldn't want to get bogged down in looking for specific "rules" that it might violate). Your text is a relatively complex juxtaposition of constructions anyway though, and I think arguably the "neatest" way to link the text before and after your comma is to replace that comma by a ***semicolon***. Then you don't want to include either ***which is*** OR ***being*** - AND it becomes just a stylistic choice whether to include the relativizer ***that*** or not.